# WCF + EF POCOs + CyclicReferencesAware attribute

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, poco

I am finding a problem using WCF + EF POCOs
I am using the CyclicReferencesAwareAttribute (meaning that object references are preserved)

The problem is that if I have the following structure:

MyEntity 
       -ItemA 
       -SubItemA
           -SubItemB
           -SubItemC
       -ItemB
           -SubItemA
           -SubItemB

When I pass the above structure from one service to another, the SubItemA and SubItemB  in the ItemB entity would be null.
Somehow these entities are lost during the serialization / deserialization process. But I cannot identify where the problem is.